# Why Is TransactionScope Not Working With Sqlite?

Tags: .net, sqlite, transactionscope

In summary, the code below creates a new table, starts a TransactionScope, inserts a row into the new table, exits the TransactionScope without calling Complete on the TransactionScope, and then gets a count of the rows in the new table. I expect the row count to be zero because the insert should have been rolled back when the TransactionScope exited without Complete having been called. In fact the code reports a row count of 1. I do get the expected zero row count when I run the code against a Sql Server database so I think the code process is correct.

I'm using v5.0.4 of the Microsoft.Data.Sqlite NuGet package and coding against .NET Framework v4.8.

Why is the insert not rolled back when the code executes against a Sqlite database?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string dbPath = @".\MyDb.db";

        using (SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source = {dbPath}"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqliteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestTable;CREATE TABLE TestTable (TestCol TEXT);";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
        {
            using (SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source = {dbPath}"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqliteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TestTable(TestCol) VALUES('Row 1')";
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            //ts.Complete();
        }

        using (SqliteConnection connection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source = {dbPath}"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqliteCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable;";
                Console.WriteLine($"Row count is {command.ExecuteScalar()}");
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After some further research, I believe the answer is - as of this writing, Microsoft.Data.Sqlite does not support TransactionScope. Here is the open GitHub item:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13825